# Evaluating probability of absolute value of stochastic integral being more than some number

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

in a book published in Japan, I came across an inequality, which I am stuck at.

Let a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq 0}, P)$ given. $X=\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a progressively measurable stochastic process with $\forall t\geq 0 ~ \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t X_s^2 ds \right]<\infty$. Prove

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:prob}
P \left( \left| \int_0^t X(s,\omega) dB_s \right| > \alpha \right) \leq P\left( \int_0^t | X(s,\omega) |^2 ds > \beta \right) + \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2},
\end{equation}

where $\alpha, \beta, t$ are some positive constants and $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a standard $\mathcal{F}_t$-Brownian motion.

I somehow managed, using Chebyshev's inequality and Ito isometry, to get

\begin{align*}
&P \left( \left| \int_0^T X(s,\omega) dB_s \right| > \alpha \right) = P \left( \left| \int_0^T X(s,\omega) dB_s \right|^2 > \alpha ^2 \right) \\ 
\leq~&\frac{1}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^T X(s,\omega) dB_s \right)^2 \right] = \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds \right] \\
=~& \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds , \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds > \beta \right] + \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds , \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds \leq \beta \right]  \right) \\
\leq~& \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \left( \beta + \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds , \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds > \beta \right] \right).
\end{align*}
Thus I need to show
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds , \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds > \beta \right] \leq P\left( \int_0^T X(s)^2 ds  > \beta \right).
$$
This is where I am stuck.

In the first place, does \ref{eq:prob} really hold? (I searched on the web or some other textbooks and I couldn't find the above inequality.)

If so, do I need a stronger evaluation for the probability $P(|\int_0^t X ~ dB_s| > \alpha)$?

Or do I need another different approach (e.g. using sub-martingale properties of $\{ |\int_0^t X ~ dB_s| \}_t$)?